# Pesquisando entre duas datas

Tags: c#, mysql

eu tenho um programa em C# que monta um relatório e consegue filtrar por nome, mas quero ir além, queria puxar todos os registros entre duas datas. Bom como eu faço para montar a WHERE desse filtro por datas ?

Tendo em vista que ja tenho uma um TableAdapter em que ele filtra meus registros por nome

Código do que filta por nome:

```
SELECT `ID_Pacote`, `Nome`, `peca`, `Quantidade`, `Data_entrada`, `Data_saida` FROM `pacote`
WHERE Nome = @nome
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92885/discussion-on-question-by-pietro-nunciaroni-pesquisando-entre-duas-datas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Teste assim:

```
SELECT `ID_Pacote`, `Nome`, `peca`, `Quantidade`, `Data_entrada`, `Data_saida` 
FROM `pacote`
WHERE data_entrada between @data1 and @data2.
```